# vb.net multi-threading activex

Tags: vb.net, multithreading

Ok, I have looked at a bazillion multi-threading examples; all show cute little counters on a form, while you can still access the form, using backgroundworker, or threadpools. I got it. What I don't get is to apply this into a real world application.
Here's my application, and I don't have a clue on how to multi-thread this;
Through a 3rd party ActiveX API I read in records to a SQL table at high rate; several million records in 8hours a day.
While the streaming of the records occurs, I need to go over the records, do some calculations and apply filters, and represent the results in realtime. (filters it down to around a 100 records/day)
I guess you see already where I'm going with this;
If I do the calculations/filters on the fly when records are streaming in; it causes the streaming to delay and I loose the connection, So I need to multi-thread the two tasks.

the streaming into SQL table is done as follows: (AxTDAAPIComm is the ActiveX)
On Form1 :

```
    Private Sub SubscrBTN_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles SubscrBTN.Click
    AxTDAAPIComm1.Subscribe(StreamOL, tdaactx.TxTDASubTypes.TDAPI_SUB_L1)
End Sub
Private Sub AxTDAAPIComm1_OnL1Quote(sender As Object, e As Axtdaactx.ITDAAPICommEvents_OnL1QuoteEvent) Handles AxTDAAPIComm1.OnL1Quote
    SQL.AddStream(e.quote.Symbol, e.quote.Bid, e.quote.Ask, e.quote.Last, e.quote.PrevClose, e.quote.Volume, e.quote.TradeTime, e.quote.QuoteTime, e.quote.TradeDate, e.quote.QuoteDate, e.quote.Volatility, e.quote.OpenInterest, e.quote.UnderlyingSymbol, e.quote.CallPut, e.quote.LastSize, e.quote.MH_LastSize, e.quote.MH_IsQuote, e.quote.MH_IsTrade)
End Sub
End Class
```

clicking on the button, invokes the AxTDAAPIComm1_OnL1Quote sub, which streams back records.
Then in my SQL Class I send it off to my SQL table:

```
    Public Sub AddStream(Symbol As String, Bid As Single, Ask As Single, Last As Single, PrevClose As Single, Volume As Integer, TradeTime As Integer, QuoteTime As Integer, TradeDate As Integer, Quotedate As Integer, Volatility As Single, OpenInterest As Integer, UnderlyingSymbol As String, CallPut As String, LastSize As Integer, MH_LastSize As Integer, MH_IsQuote As Boolean, MH_IsTrade As Boolean)
    Try
        Dim TradeAmount As Single = 0
        Dim Trade As String = ""
        TradeAmount = LastSize * Last * 100
        Select Case Last
            Case Is = Ask
                Trade = "Ask"
            Case Is > Ask
                Trade = "Above Ask"
            Case Is = Bid
                Trade = "Bid"
            Case Is < Bid
                Trade = "Below Bid"
            Case Else
                Trade = "Mid"
        End Select


        Dim strStream As String = "INSERT INTO OptionStream (Symbol,Bid,Ask,Last,PrevClose,Volume,TradeTime,QuoteTime,TradeDate,QuoteDate,Volatility,OpenInterest,UnderlyingSymbol,CallPut,TradeAmount,Trade,LastSize,MH_LastSize,MH_IsQuote,MH_IsTrade) " & _
                                  "VALUES (" & _
                                  "'" & Symbol & "'," & _
                                  "'" & Bid & "'," & _
                                  "'" & Ask & "'," & _
                                  "'" & Last & "'," & _
                                  "'" & PrevClose & "'," & _
                                  "'" & Volume & "'," & _
                                  "'" & TradeTime & "'," & _
                                  "'" & QuoteTime & "'," & _
                                  "'" & TradeDate & "'," & _
                                  "'" & Quotedate & "'," & _
                                  "'" & Volatility & "'," & _
                                  "'" & OpenInterest & "'," & _
                                  "'" & UnderlyingSymbol & "'," & _
                                  "'" & CallPut & "'," & _
                                  "'" & TradeAmount & "'," & _
                                  "'" & Trade & "'," & _
                                  "'" & LastSize & "'," & _
                                  "'" & MH_LastSize & "'," & _
                                  "'" & MH_IsQuote & "'," & _
                                  "'" & MH_IsTrade & "') "


        SQLCon.Open()
        SQLCmd = New SqlCommand(strStream, SQLCon)
        SQLCmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        SQLCon.Close()


    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try

End Sub
```

On my Form I have created a text box, which I use to enter a SQL query statement, which I capture as follows:

```
   Private Sub cmdQuery_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cmdQuery.Click
    If txtQuery.Text <> "" Then
        If SQL.HasConnection = True Then
            SQL.RunQueryWL(txtQuery.Text)
            If SQL.SQLDatasetWL.Tables.Count > 0 Then
                DGVData.DataSource = SQL.SQLDatasetWL.Tables(0)
            End If
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

As you can see, it now goes of to the SQL class and runs the Query:

```
    Public Function HasConnection() As Boolean
    Try
        SQLCon.Open()
        SQLCon.Close()
        Return True
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
        Return False
    End Try
End Function
Public Sub RunQueryWL(Query As String)
    Try
        SQLCon.Open()
        SQLCmd = New SqlCommand(Query, SQLCon)
        SQLDA = New SqlDataAdapter(SQLCmd)
        SQLDatasetWL = New DataSet
        SQLDA.Fill(SQLDatasetWL)
        SQLCon.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
        If SQLCon.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
            SQLCon.Close()
        End If
    End Try
End Sub
```

and the result is presented in a datagrid view on my form.
As you can imagine, querying against a couple million records takes a few seconds, therefore I want to put the AxTDAAPIComm1.Subscribe and AxTDAAPIComm1_OnL1Quote and the RunQueryWL Subs on different threads.

How do I do this?